# Compose E-Mail from anyone@example.com in Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I use Google Apps with [Catch-all](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962?hl=en) filter. Now since I am the only user at my domain, I want to send the E-Mail the from anyone@example.com without verifying each username since I own all of them and they are just catch all. Is their any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but you have to make it by creating each pseudo-email account of your domain as an alias through Admin Console. You cannot just simply type whatever pseudo-email (alias) account you want each time you want to reply with it without having set it up before.

**First you create an alias**

Admin Console > Users > Account > Aliases : Add an alias > someuser@yourdomain.com

**Then you configure your Gmail to make use of the alias you created as a sender**

Gmail Mailbox > Gear icon > Settings > Accounts > Send Mail as : Add another email address that you own

You put the name you want, you enter the alias you created (someuser@gmail.com), you tick the "Treat as an alias" box and you are ready to go.

Now you can select this alias as a sender when you compose or reply to an email. You can create limitless aliases since they are not real users where you have to purchase a seperate Google Apps subscription.